# java format timestamps with "Z" instead of "+"

Tags: java, java-8, jodatime

Using java I try to format the current date with the timezone using SimpleDateFormat

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ");
sdf.format(new Date());
```

This give me as results :

```
   2021-04-28T13:45:52:308+0300
```

I want to get the timezone format with the "Z" instead of "+"

wanted results :   `"2021-04-28T13:45:52:308Z03:00"`

I writed the date output in a file log that will be parsed by telegraf plugin writed in Go language that expect date with time zone with the following format : `json_time_format = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"`

Is there a pattern allows that ?

Comment: If you are using at least Java 8, consider using the [date-time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) API.

Comment: @Abra Even if you're not, it's been backported.

Comment: this's a legacy code

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). If you need to rewrite your legacy code anyway, do your self the favour of rewriting it using java.time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood. `2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00` does not mean that you should have a `Z` instead of a plus (what would you put instead of a minus, then?) This way of specifying a date and time format approximates how the fixed example date and time of Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006 would be formatted, but it’s only an approximation. Specifically when it comes to the offset from UTC, the format requires `Z` when the offset is zero and `+hh:mm` or `-hh:mm` when it is non-zero. In accordance with ISO 8601 and RFC-3339. You see immediately that just giving the correct formatting of the example date and time, `2006-01-02T15:04:05-07:00`, would not tell the reader that offset 0 should be given as `Z`. Therefore this particular requirement is specified as `Z07:00` in the format. According to *Format a time or date [complete guide]* (link at the bottom), your particular format, `2006-01-02T15:04:05-0700`, denotes ISO 8601 or RFC-3339.

So all you need to do is use `DateTimeFormat.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` or `OffsetDateTime.toString()`.

A couple of examples follow.

```
    String result = OffsetDateTime.now().toString();
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output when running on Java 8 in my time zone just now:

2021-04-29T17:00:55.716+02:00

If the fraction of second is not allowed — well, according to ISO 8601 it is optional, so it should be, but if not:

```
    String result = OffsetDateTime.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.SECONDS)
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```

> 2021-04-29T17:00:55+02:00

If you have got an old-fashioned `Date` object from legacy code, convert it before formatting:

```
    Date oldfashionedDate = new Date();
    String result = oldfashionedDate.toInstant()
            .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
            .format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
```

> 2021-04-29T17:00:55.739+02:00

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Wikipedia article: ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601)
- [Format a time or date [complete guide]](https://yourbasic.org/golang/format-parse-string-time-date-example/)

Answer (score 2):

Z is for "Zulu time" or zero hour offset, i.e. UTC +0:00

It's not correct to use it if you're not in that timezone. How would you know whether you're before or after the meridian if you replace it with `Z`? Given `Z03:00` do you parse it as `+03:00` or `-03:00`?

Comment: I have write the date output in the file log that parsed by telegraf go plugin that expect date with time zone with the following format :  json_time_format = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"

Answer (score 2):

Since Z means Zulu time offset you can't use it as part of the format string but you can of course add `Z` as a hardcoded character

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now();
  
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'Z");
System.out.println(formatter.format(now));
```

> 2021-04-29T15:34:17.661Z+0200

Then if you don't want the '+' you can remove it afterwards but it is not clear on what to do whit a '-' so I left it out of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Semantically as mentioned above its quite wrong.But you can achieve this with some custom parsing logic.
I will assume 2 things:

1. The date will not contain timezones with negative differences
2. The date format will not change

In any other cases, this is not safe!!
But here you go:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:SSSZ");
String originalDateString = sdf.format(new Date());
String[] parts = originalDateString.split("\\+");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(parts[1]);
sb.insert(2, ':');
parts[1] = sb.toString();
String result = String.join("Z",parts);
System.out.println(result);
```

This will create from this:
2021-04-29T14:12:21:376+0000

This:
2021-04-29T14:12:21:376Z00:00

Comment: Please don’t teach the young ones to use the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class. At least not as the first option. And not without any reservation. We have so much better in [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) and its `DateTimeFormatter`.

Comment: I know, and I agree with you. The reasons is i have included this in the answer is:
1. The poster used it in the example he provided
2. The poster mentioned its a legacy code - thus possibly cant be changed.

Comment: The question is tagged with java-8 so the java.time api should be available